# How do I configure my Network to connect through my router to my cable modem

Tags: router, static-routes

I think there is probably a better title for this question, I'll ater it once I've figured out the right terms

I have the following setup at home

```
Internet -> Cisco Cable Modem/Router -> Dlink DIR-655 --> My Laptop
            192.168.10.1                10.0.0.1          10.0.0.14
```

I want to be able to get to the Cisco's configuration page from my Laptop. I think it might be something to do with setting up a route from the DIR-655 to the Cisco but I can't figure out how to configure this correctly.

Comment: What's the model name of the Cisco cable modem / router?

Comment: Model is Cisco DPC3825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that setup, you should be able to reach the Cisco configuration page on `192.168.10.1`. The Dlink will NAT it, and the cable modem will have no problem thinking it's talking to the Dlink. But you have double-NAT in that setup and you should avoid it unless you have no choice.

Do you have two routers for a reason? If not, change the cable modem to operate in bridging mode.

Comment: The 2 routers is because my ISP provided me with a new Cisco cable modem but I'd much prefer to use my dlink router with all my configured firewall rules

Comment: Then switch the modem to bridging mode and stop using it as a router. Double-NAT just makes problems. (Just remember, you can't use the modem's wireless in that configuration.)

Comment: Bridiging mode seems to be the solution, I need to call my ISP and get them to provision it (according to some forums I've been reading)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to go to the DLink's web configuration http://10.0.0.1 and disable the DHCP server on the DLink router. This will make the devices connected to the internal switch of the DLink router pull an IP address from your Cisco one.